# filtering table using two columns

Tags: jquery, tabulator

I have table with several columns and I want to filter on two of the columns we will call `feature` and `comments`.  The below jquery works fine for filtering on `feature`, but I want to include another column.

```
$("#tabulator-controls input[name=feature]").on("keyup", function(){
  table.setFilter( "feature", "like", $(this).val())
});
```

Would I use an or statement like so?

```
$("#tabulator-controls input[name=feature], input[name=comments]").on("keyup", function(){
  table.setFilter( "feature", "like", $(this).val()),
  table.setFilter( "comments", "like", $(this).val())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you wish to apply multiple filters then you can pass an array of filter objects to this function, the data will then have to pass all filters to be displayed in the table.

```
$("#tabulator-controls").on("keyup", "input[name='feature'], input[name='comments']", function(){
  table.setFilter([
    { field: "feature", type: "like", value: $(this).val() },
    { field: "comments", type: "like", value: $(this).val() }
  ]);
});
```

See More: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/filter

Comment: Thanks!  I think I'm missing something.  I still seem to be only filtering by `feature`.  Here's the HTML portion.  `<input class="filterbox" name="feature" type="text" placeholder="Filter Table By Feature">`.  I tried using `name=feature` for both inputs but no change.

Comment: @Robert Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I'm not sure I am even looking at the right Docs for the plugin you're using.